# Return Date modified in Epoch ms using stat

Tags: macos, terminal, stat

I'm trying to get a list of file along with their modified time. I'm currently using `find ~/Desktop -print0 | xargs -0 stat -f '%m %N'` but this is only accurate to the second. Is there a way to format it for ms? I've tried google searches but a bit new to this and unsure of the terminology

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default `stat` not giving milliseconds, you need to install coreutils :

```
brew install coreutils
```

Then

```
find ~/Desktop -print0 | xargs -0 /usr/local/Cellar/coreutils/8.31/libexec/gnubin/stat --format='%.3Y %N'
```

Comment: Thats a shame. Was hoping for a native solution. Thanks for the info